# Insert an array into an existing array Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

How can I add an array into an existing array using MongoDB/Meteor ? Here is the structure of the database.

[image]

I want to add a new array inside [depute] and not a new array outside, like it is now.

So far, this is the code.

```
Meteor.methods({
    'votes.insert': function (depute, loi, choix){
        console.log('from votes.insert', depute, loi, choix)
        return Deputies.update(depute,
           {$push: {votes: {[loi]:choix}}}
        );
    },
});
```

It adds a new array [votes], next to [depute], instead of being inside [depute].

Any hint ?

Comment: Try `Deputies.update(depute,            {$push: {'depute.votes': {[loi]:choix}}}         );` It doesn't  look like depute is an array, it is a emdedded document.

Comment: Here is the structure of the json file {
  "deputes" : [ {
    "depute" : {
      "adresses" : [ {
        "adresse" : "this is the address"
      } ],
      "anciens_mandats" : [ {

Comment: What is the search criteria to insert votes array ? Which depute array element you require to push votes into ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact, that javascript arrays can be referenced like objects using the index as a property.

So you create your `object.property` pattern using your `loi` variable:

```
const selector = `votes.${loi}`;
```

Which would create for `loi===0` the selector `"votes.0`.

**Code example:**

```
Meteor.methods({
    'votes.insert': function (depute, loi, choix){
        console.log('from votes.insert', depute, loi, choix)
        const selector = `votes.${loi}`;
        return Deputies.update(dpute, { $push: { [selector]: choix } });
    },
});
```

**Example outputs:**

`votes === []` and `choix === 5` will result for `loi === 0` in `votes: [ [ 5 ] ]`

`votes === [[1]]` and `choix === 5` will result for `loi === 0` in `votes: [ [ 1, 5 ] ]`

`votes === [[1]]` and `choix === 5` will result for `loi === 1` in `votes: [ [ 1 ], [ 5 ] ] }`

Comment: It adds a new array inside deputy._id but outside of depute array

Comment: You question was a bit confusing, I misunderstood. My apologies. Please add next time a more clear expected output (e.g. the structure of the resulting document) and also the schema of your collection. By reading your comment on the answer from @sean it seems, that depute has the schema type `ObjectId`. Are you using mongoose or something?

Comment: Sorry for the non so clear question, very newbie to this! I use meteor/mongodb. The output expected should be deputy.id>[depute]>[votes]

Comment: Then you may just change in the code from my example `votes` to `depute`. If you get the error, that depute needs to be an array then you might check your collection's schema.

Comment: I could make it work thank you , just adding const selector = `depute.votes.${loi}`; each "loi is saved inside depute>votes

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using `$push` won't work as you intend. You need to specify that you want to push something in to `depute` but instead you are pushing into `votes`, therefore just creating `votes` on the parent object.

The syntax you are looking for is:

```
// create your votes array using your args loi & choix up here:
const votes = [ ... ]

// push the votes array in to depute here:
Deputies.update(depute,
    {$push: {depute: votes}
);
```

Comment: I come up with this code  
const votes=[{[loi]:choix}];
return Deputies.update(depute,
{$push: {depute:votes}}

but it returns this error: Exception while invoking method 'votes.insert' MongoError: The field 'depute' must be an array but is of type Object in document {_id: "cjiCj2HmtsPpB87ZT"}